# how to set horizontal scroll to horizontal field manager

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, horizontal-scrolling

The following snippet contains a horizontal field manager to which five buttons are added.

**1.** I am unable to set horizontal scroll to the horizontal field manager because of which I am not able to access button 4 and button 5.

**2.** Usually we set horizontal scroll in the following manner

```java
horizontalFieldManager = 
    new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH|HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_LEFT|HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
```

but since I have added the buttons in the constructor of the horizontal field manager I am unable to use this.

**3.** I found this property :  `horizontalFieldManager.setHorizontalScroll(position);`
which contains the Parameter:position  where position is supposed to be the new horizontal scroll position.  I tried passing the x-coordinate of the horizontal field manager but it's not working. What should i pass as the `position` parameter?

```java
HorizontalFieldManager container = new HorizontalFieldManager()
{  
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
    {   
        Field field = null;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int maxFieldHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getFieldCount(); i++) 
        {
            field = getField(i);
            layoutChild(field, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setPositionChild(field, x,y);
            x+=field.getWidth();
            if(i==0)
            {
                maxFieldHeight = field.getHeight(); // height set of the first button since all components have the same height
            }
        }

        setExtent(Display.getWidth(), maxFieldHeight);

    }
};

ButtonField button1 = new ButtonField("Button1");
ButtonField button2 = new ButtonField("Button2");
ButtonField button3 = new ButtonField("Button3");
ButtonField button4 = new ButtonField("Button4");
ButtonField button5 = new ButtonField("Button5");

container.add(button1);
container.add(button2);
container.add(button3);
container.add(button4);
container.add(button5);

add(container);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HorizontalFieldManager Constructor

If you simply change the way you call the `HorizontalFieldManager` constructor, from this:

```java
HorizontalFieldManager container = new HorizontalFieldManager() {
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
```

to this:

```java
HorizontalFieldManager container = 
    new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR) {

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
```

then, you'll get the ability to scroll horizontally, and reach all five buttons.

---

### sublayout()

In your `sublayout()` method, you appear to be laying out your fields just as `HorizontalFieldManager` would normally do.  So, I don't think there's any point in adding that code.  Simply do this:

```java
HorizontalFieldManager container = 
   new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);

ButtonField button1 = new ButtonField("Button1");
/* the rest of your code is the same */
```

If you later want to control spacing between the buttons, do it with *margins*:

```java
  ButtonField button1 = new ButtonField("Button1");
  button1.setMargin(10, 10, 10, 10);
  ButtonField button2 = new ButtonField("Button2");
  button2.setMargin(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

In general, it's usually not a good idea to use a `HorizontalFieldManager`, or a `VerticalFieldManager` and **also** override `sublayout()`.  If you really want custom behavior there, you should probably just extend `Manager` directly with a subclass of your own.

Comment: ... and what happened?  I tested this code, and when you use that constructor, the field can be scrolled.  It's not clear to me whether you just want the **user** to be able to scroll the buttons to the right (to see button 4 and 5), or whether you want the **code** to automatically scroll over to the 4th and 5th button, hiding the first two.  Can you provide some more information?

Comment: I tried calling HorizontalFieldManager container = 
    new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR) {

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {   instead of HorizontalFieldManager container = new HorizontalFieldManager() {
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) { // here i added the fields using a for loop as mentioned in the code snippet but its not working. Am i missing something?

Comment: Hi Nate, I want the user to be able to scroll the buttons to the right to view button 4 and 5.

Comment: On your first comment: you're still overriding the `sublayout()` method.  Please see my full answer, as I recommend **not** doing that.  See the section I titled **sublayout()** in my updated answer.  If you do this, the user will be able to scroll to the right to buttons 4 and 5 by finger swiping (or using the trackwheel) within the HorizontalFieldManager's area.

Comment: Thank you. As u said in my sublayout() method, I appear to be laying out my fields just as HorizontalFieldManager would normally do so I have finally decided to opt for the latter.